# How do I survive in lane against Ezreal?

Tags: league-of-legends

Pulsefire Ezreal came out and there's been a lot more Ezreal players. He's hard to gank with just one rank in his Arcane Shift and hard to harass with his Essence Flux going over minions and slowing my attack speed. Trinity does so well on him that he can build just a Phage and survive and burst for someone like Graves. How can I farm in lane without having to worry about him killing me?

Is there a particular champion or support that counters him particularly well?

Answer (score 2):

The best way i have found to beat an ezreal in lane is to be in a kill lane with leona, blitz, alistar, or taric and make him use his arcane shift if you know a gank from your jungler is coming by using cc on him or pressuring by harrass.

Cooldowns are ezreals worst enemy.

Graves is a very strong pick against ezreal also, because he has the gap closer and great burst that is not too dependent on attack speed, countering ezreals W. Corki is another very strong pick, you have the gap closer and armor shred because he's a very squishy AD early game. Also, the non-auto-attack damage they both have is very great.

Answer (score 2):

Ezreal is naturally strong because his high mobility and burst lets him leap in and trade reasonably well with most heroes. His weakness, however, is that he's exceptionally squishey and shorter range, rendering him weak to burst and enemy poke compared to most other heroes.

This leaves 2 forms of counterplay against an ezreal.

1. Exploit his early squishiness. Using lanes that involve supports like: taric, leona and alistar and AD carries such as: Urgot, Graves, and Corki really lets you abuse him before he gets extreme mobility or extreme burst.

Avoid using blitz to do this. While he is strong and aggressive, the interaction between arcane shift and blitz hook favors ezreal to the point where he can shift almost after the pull and still get out.

2 2. Exploit his short range. This is a little trickier because ezreal's e lets him close gaps well, but doing so puts him under heavy risk from jungler presence. This means that getting an AD carry who gets really fast range can place ezreal in a rough place.

The goal is to get a strong damage mitigation support such as: janna, soraka, or taric as well as a carry like kog' maw or urgot who can poke ezreal outside his auto range. It takes a lot of play around creeps and understanding of ranges, but generally (especially in the case of kog maw) generally outscales ezreal.

Tristana and caitlyn, however aren't good for this strat. Ezreal has a significantly stronger lanephase than Tristana, and because he can duck her early game burst, it renders her in a spot where she isn't really strong until LATE, lategame unless ezreal mistimes his arcane shifts. Caitlyn is overreliant on bush control, which while good on most heroes isn't good vs ezreal simply because his q range  can outpoke her auto range.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to say because so much depends on the supports, a good kill lane (Corki/leona, Vayne/Nunu, Slivir/Taric) will hurt him as EZ goes down EZ being quite squishy.

But if hes with someone who can keep him out of trouble like Janna/ali/ he can just poke a kill lane till there hp is down and they can't be as aggressive, so a good sustain support would be nice.

Its a very general question as too much depends on supports for him to be hard countered, but i like Slivir vs Him as its easy to get the spell shield off to stop his ult or bait some of his pokes to get some mana back

Answer (score 1):

I pick Cait; you can push the lane easily, and poke Ez while he's under the turret with Q. While he tries to farm, stand behind the minions (so you don't get hit), and have a good support like Lulu nearby; she can poke him down and make him water his mana.

When Ez comes forward to attack, you can use Cait's E to side dodge and avoid the skill shots. However, don't waste your mana in lane, or he'll easily beat you.